# Как узнать все индексы заданного элемента в массиве?

Tags: ruby

Возможно ли узнать все индексы заданного элемента в массиве? Если да, то как? Пробовал решить данную задачу через метод "index", но он возвращает индекс только для первого попавшегося элемента в массиве. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

**Пример массива:**

```
[ "|" , "a", "b", "|", "c," "d" , "f" , "|" , "|" ]
```

**Примерная задача:**

> Узнать все индексы со значением "|" .

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```
arr =  ["|" , "a", "b", "|", "c", "d" , "f" , "|" , "|"] 
a = (0 ... arr.length).find_all { |i| arr[i] == '|' }
```

Ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Или так:

```
.map.with_index{ |e, i| i if e == "|" }.compact
```